# How to know the scrolled (top hidden cells/rows count) cells count in the ui TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

In my app **i need to display 1000s of contacts in a table view.**

**it is very hard to scroll the table view and apps gets slow**

so for this *i want to display only some limited (10) number of rows in the table view*

for this i want to use

**`SELECT * FROM  ContactTitles order by CT_Title desc  LIMIT 10 OFFSET HiddenCellsCount;`**

```
 SELECT * FROM  ContactTitles order by CT_Title desc  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
 SELECT * FROM  ContactTitles order by CT_Title desc  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1;
 SELECT * FROM  ContactTitles order by CT_Title desc  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2;
 SELECT * FROM  ContactTitles order by CT_Title desc  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 990;
```

here every time OFFSET need to change with respect to the top hidden / scrolled cells count

```
how to get the count of scrolled rows count in a table view.?.
```

And is there any alter nate to reduce the slowdown of my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first load only a few cells and then fetch more as the user scrolls down. For this you can use:

```
   - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {


        NSInteger currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        NSInteger maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height + scrollView.frame.size.height;


        if (maximumOffset-currentOffset==maximumOffset)// is at the last row
        {
// your code here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the offset using

```
tableView.visibleCells.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this with SQLITE try to do this with Core Data, and setBatchSize 20 or something, it will not slows your app.